# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript, dialog

I have this error when i moving between dialogs. This shows up, when i am returning from the child dialog to the parent. Any idea what cause the problem? This is the function that i am using for this, it works for other examples.

```
 var _getCurrentDialogId = function (windowObj) {
    return $(windowObj.frameElement.parentNode).attr("id");
};
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Comment: So what is your problem? frameElement clearly holds no value, so fix it.

Comment: `windowObj.frameElement` return the element which the windowObj is embedded into, or null if the windowObj is top-level

Comment: We have no idea what you are passing in to this. Your snippet is meaningless without some context

Comment: So i have to change target="_top" to something else?